# Split the string using XSLT to extarct link

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, lxml

I am trying to solve a simple calculation but failed. I am using `XSLT 1.0`. I have a sample example XML.

```
<root>
    <slide add_info="Retail" name="slide41.xml" nav_lvl_1="Link Slide" nav_lvl_2="" page_number="41">
        <Text>
            <links>Go for a test-drive, visit us online at http://google.com</links>
            <links>Also, visit our community pages to learn more:</links>
            <links>http://google.com/community/retail</links>
        </Text>
    </slide>
</root>
```

I want to `split the string` where the first part would be text and second part would be the link starting with `http`. There are cases as shown above, where there might exists only text and no link or only link and no text. So I to split and put the `text and link in separate nodes`. For example:

```
    <root>
        <slide add_info="Retail" name="slide41.xml" nav_lvl_1="Link Slide" nav_lvl_2="" page_number="41">
            <split_1>
                 <link_text>Go for a test-drive, visit us online at </link_text>
                 <link_link>http://google.com</link_link>

            </split_1>
        </slide>
    </root>
```

Do i have to use regex for this or do i have `any functions` through which I can do this. I cannot use XSLT 2.0.

Expected output:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Go for a test-drive, visit us online at </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:hyperlink r:id="rId7" w:history="1">
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00E8727D">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>http://google.com/</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:hyperlink>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Also, visit our community pages to learn more:</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:hyperlink r:id="rId7" w:history="1">
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00E8727D">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>http://google.com/community/retail</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:hyperlink>
</w:p>
```

Comment: Could you paste how your expected output xml should look like for your example? Including the 'Also, visit..' and the retail link.

Comment: @AdolfoPerez I have put up the expected output up there!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSL should include a template something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="links">
     <xsl:if test="contains(text(), 'http:')">
         <split_1>
            <xsl:variable name="before">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(), 'http:')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <link_text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$before"/>
            </link_text>
            <link_link>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(), $before)" />
            </link_link>
        </split_1>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```